# Micro SD Card 32G - will the SanDisk Pixtor work with the new 3DSXL? It's an SDSDQUP-032Q-AB46A. It's an SDHC1

Tags: new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

Planning to re-transfer to the new card from the old 3DSXL. Did not delete on the last transfer and noticed that I only had 3K plus blocks after reloading MH4U. Decided to get a 32G card but didn't see the version I had listed on the recommended list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nintendo's [official statement](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/274/~/what-sd-cards-and-microsd-cards-are-compatible%3F) is that microSDHC cards of 5GB and larger ([up to 32GB](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13995/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDI1MTg2MDI1L3NpZC8qSmhYdGJnbQ%3D%3D)) are compatible with the 3D SXL.

Your particular card model is not on the [list of tested models](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13995/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDI1MTg2MDI1L3NpZC8qSmhYdGJnbQ%3D%3D), but it appears to otherwise meet the requirements of the 3DS XL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I'll repost with the results.